# Can I set requestor as not my own server but Client on nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, api, request

First of All, Sorry for my poor english and Thanks for clicking this Question.

I want to make just GUI service(simple html though) that using APIs from another Web Servers.

My Service do only provide 'html button' that request to other APIs.

So I just coded POST method form on html that transffering APIkey and SecretKey.

I used 'uuid', 'jsonwebtoken' modules to process APIkey and Secretkey. (API provider needed this)

and also used 'request' module to request APIs.

here is my part of code.

```js
...

const request = require('request');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const sign = require('jsonwebtoken').sign

...

,(req, res)=>{
  const access_key = req.keydata.apikey;
  const secret_key = req.keydata.secret;
  const server_url = "https://api.url.com";

  const payload = {
      access_key: access_key,
      nonce: uuidv4(),
  };

  const token = sign(payload, secret_key);

  const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: server_url + "/v1/foo",
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
  }

  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      res.send(body);
  })

...
```

but on this way, Not Client do, but I do request to other APIs.

I want to set requestor as Client. Not way of my server do request.

Can I send to client 'token' that made by my server with APIkey & secKey ?

after that, client do XHR to API with custom header including token.

Is there any Security problem on this way?

or Is there any other way that changing requestor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I send to client 'token' that made by my server with APIkey & secKey ?

Yes.  In fact, this is fairly common, a regular thing to do.  (For example, users of AWS S3 will sign URLs and send those to the clients.  The clients will actually make the request to S3 directly.)

You can simply use JSON to return the URL and headers that the client should use.

> after that, client do XHR to API with custom header including token.

You can use XHR if you want, but check out the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  It's easier to work with, and is well supported by browsers.

> Is there any Security problem on this way?

Not really.  Just make sure you're using HTTPS everywhere, so that your signed URL cannot be intercepted and used by someone else.